# AppCenter doesn't seem to run pod install despite existence of Podfile

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

I've got a react-native app that builds on AppCenter. I have a `Podfile` in my `/ios` directory, and locally, I can run `pod install`. The AppCenter documentation says that "App Center scans the selected branch and if it finds a Podfile, it will automatically do a pod install step at the beginning of every build. This will ensure that all dependencies are installed.", but as far as I can tell, it's not running `pod install` for my build and the build fails for that reason.

Tried adding `pod install` to a pre-build script, in which case the build succeeds.

Comment: Can you post a link to the doc where it says that it scans & run the `pod install` command?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/first-build#38-cocoapods

Comment: Which version of react-native do you have? It matters.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that in addition to having a *Podfile*, [you must NOT have a *ios/Pods* folder present in the remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/#38-cocoapods). In my case, I also had to explicitly add that folder to my *.gitignore*

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the Cocoapods version running on the build agent matches the one on your podfile.lock.

You can add a post clone script like this on your ios/ folder:

[appcenter-post-clone.sh](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/react-native/compare-cocoapods/appcenter-post-clone.sh) This will automatically install the matching cocoapods version.

Push that file to your repo, then make sure you open the build configuration and hit Save and Build.